# Slim Frameworks variável entre rotas

Tags: php, slim

Como passar resultado de uma rota para outra no Slim Frameworks

ex:

```
$app->get('/rota1/:param', function($param) use ($app, $myclass) {
    // rotina que retornará um array
    $myArr = $myclass->method($param);
});

$app->get('/rota2', function() use ($app) {
    // rotina para processar o array da rota1
    print_r($myArr);
});
```

Comment: Acho que apenas por GET, POST, COOKIE ou SESSION?

Comment: Sim, string não tão longas é possível com [URL For](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/#url-for)